# Running configure file in MinGW64: default build_alias command and default prefix not found

Tags: build, configure, mingw-w64, msys2

I'm using MinGW64 via an MSYS2 download and am currently trying to install the Solar Geometry 2 library (http://www.oie.mines-paristech.fr/Valorisation/Outils/Solar-Geometry/) for use. I'm following their install README, which states to navigate to the directory and "configure" (I've been typing "./configure". However, when I do so, I get the following message in my terminal:

```
   $ ./configure
    configure: loading site script /mingw64/etc/config.site
    /mingw64/etc/config.site: line 13: config.site:13: default build_alias set to x6_64-w64-mingw32: command not found
    /mingw64/etc/config.site: line 20: config.site:20: default prefix set to /mingw4: No such file or directory
    configure: error: cannot find install-sh or install.sh in . ./.. ./../..
```

When I initially installed MSYS2 I set up the etc/fstab file as recommended. However, I'm quite new to MSYS so I'm assuming I botched something in my setup. I haven't edited anything in the config.site file mentioned in the errors, so I'm wondering if it's something in there.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1):

No where in the directions for "Solar Geometry" do I see reference to MSys or MSys2.

I suggest you install the compiler toolchain and base development file. No idea if you editing /etc/fstab will cause problems. I do not normmaly edit it!

Install MinGW Package build packages. You might need more packages installed.

```
pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
```